# Change Color of Image as a node using vis.js

Tags: javascript, vis.js

Hi I am trying to change the color of an image attached as a node. Using `vis.js` is there a way we can do this?

I tried to use this :

```
{data.nodes.update([{id:[i], color:{border:'#9966ff'}}]);}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please explain more ! what do you really want ? by Image you mean node style ? what component are you using ? ....

Comment: I am trying to create a network topology with routers and switches connected . I am using router image as a node. I want to change its color (for example, to green) when a button is clicked, indicating that the network is up and running. I am trying to add color on top of a router or change the image color if possible.

Comment: Did you try `nodes.update({id: someID, color:{border:'#9966ff'}});`

Comment: Yes. I tried that also. But doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You first have to declare your nodes as a data set

```
var nodes = new vis.DataSet();
nodes.add([
    {id: 1, label:"myLabel}
]);
```

Then call a function to update the nodes:

```
function changeData(){
        nodes.update({id: 1, color: {background: "orange"}});
}
```

Then have a button call that function:

```
<button onClick="changeData()">Click Here</button>
```

Cheers!